# Vanishing for Ext of coherent sheaves on a smooth Noetherian scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F,G$ be coherent sheaves on a smooth Noetherian scheme $X$ of dimension $n$. I can see that $Ext^k(F,G) = 0$ for $k > 2n$. Is this sharp? Or can it perhaps be improved to get vanishing for $k>n$?

The argument I have in mind is to use the spectral sequence $H^i(\mathcal{Ext}^j(F,G)) \Rightarrow Ext^{i+j}(F,G)$. Since $\mathcal{Ext}^j(F,G)$ can be computed locally on affine charts using a projective resolution, we have $\mathcal{Ext}^j(F,G) = 0$ for $j > n$ by smoothness. Moreover
$\mathcal{Ext}^j(F,G)$ is coherent, so by the Grothendieck vanishing theorem we have $H^i(\mathcal{Ext}^j(F,G)) = 0$ for $i > n$. So the $E_2$ page of the spectral sequence is already zero outside the box $(i,j) \in [0,n] \times [0,n]$, and in particular for $i+j > 2n$.

But perhaps something more subtle happens?

Comment: A trivial remark : if $F$ is locally free (i.e a vector bundle) then this $Ext^k(F,G) \cong H^k(X,F^* \otimes G)$ which vanishes for $k  > n$.

Comment: If $X$ is projective over a field, you can use Serre duality to prove the vanishing for $k > n$.

Comment: @Sasha: could you please give a proof of how to do $k>n$ when $X$ is projective over a field? I have asked a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339322/vanishing-of-ext-groups-of-coherent-sheaves-over-noetherian-regular-scheme-of-di

Comment: @SnakeEyes: By Serre duality $Ext^{n+p}(F,G) \cong Ext^{-p}(G,F \otimes \omega_X)^\vee$, and for $p > 0$ this vanishes because $G$ and $F \otimes \omega_X$ are both coherent sheaves.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: Serre duality holds for any objects of the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective variety (read about Serre functors).